# A confusion about UFDs

Tags: unique-factorization-domains

So I'm new to this concept and when I was reading the definition.
It says that if R is a UFD then every non zero element can be written as the product of irreducible elements.
So here's my question which is stupid I know.
Are these irreducible elements necessarily distinct??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the integers are a unique factorization domain and $4=2 \cdot 2$.  You have to include the possibility of a unit, which for the integers can only be $-1$, to get the negatives.

Comment: Thanks, now can I say that each element can be written like $p_1^{a_1}....p_n^{a_n}$ where ps are primes?? (It says that irriducable elements are prime elements in UFDs)

Comment: Yes, that is correct if you put in a unit.